# Need help setting up django-filetransfers

Tags: django, file-upload, django-forms

My setup is: Django 1.3/Python 2.7.2/Win Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.5/MS SQL Server 2008 R2. I am developing an application whose main function is to analyze uploaded files and produce a report.

Reading over the documentation for [django-filetransfers](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers), I believe this is a solution to a problem I've been trying to solve for a while (i.e. form-based file uploads completely block *all* Django responses until the file-transfer finishes...horror for even moderate-sized files).

The documentation talks about piping uploads to S3 or Blobstore, and that might be what I end up doing eventually, but during development I thought maybe I could just set up my own "poor-man's S3" on a server that I control. This would basically just be another Django instance (or possibly a simple ASP.NET app) whose sole purpose is to receive uploaded files. This sounds like it should be possible with django-filetransfers and would solve the problem of Django responsiveness (???).

But I am missing some bits of understanding how this works in general, as well as some specifics. Maybe an example will help: let's say I have MyMainDjangoServer and MyFileUploadServer. MyMainDjangoServer will serve the views, including the upload form. MyFileUploadServer will "catch" the uploaded files. My questions/confusion are as follows:

- My upload form will contain additional fields beyond just the file(s)...do I understand correctly that MyMainDjangoServer will somehow still get that form data, minus the file data  (basically: request.POST), and the file data gets shunted over to MyFileUploadServer? How does this work? Will MyMainDjangoServer still block during the upload to MyFileUploadServer?
- I assume that what I would need to do on MyFileUploadServer is have a view/URL that handles the form request and sucks out the request.FILES data. What else needs to happen? What happens to the rest of the form data?
- How would I set up my settings.py for this scenario? The django-filetransfers examples seem to assume either S3 or GAE/Blobstore but maybe I am missing some basics.

Any advice/answers appreciated...this is a confusing and frustrating area of Django for me.

Answer (score 2):

*"MyMainDjangoServer will somehow still get that form data, minus the file data (basically: request.POST), and the file data gets shunted over to MyFileUploadServer? How does this work? Will MyMainDjangoServer still block during the upload to MyFileUploadServer?"*

I know the GAE Blobstore, presumably S3 as well, handles this by requiring you to give it a `success_url`. In your case that would be the url on `MyMainDjangoServer` where your file receiving view on `MyFileUploadServer` would re-post the non-files form data to once the upload is complete.

Have a look at the `create_upload_url` method here:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions

You need to recreate this functionality in some form (see below).

*"How would I set up my settings.py for this scenario?"*

You'd need to create your own filetransfers backend which would be a file with a `prepare_upload` function in it.

You can see the App Engine one here:
https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine/blob/develop/storage.py

The `prepare_upload` method just wraps the GAE `create_upload_url` method mentioned above.

So in your settings.py you'd have something like:

```
PREPARE_UPLOAD_BACKEND = 'myapp.filetransfers_backend.prepare_upload'
```

(i.e. the import path to your `prepare_upload` function)

For the rest you can start with the ones provided by filetransfers already:

```
SERVE_FILE_BACKEND = 'filetransfers.backends.url.serve_file'
# if you need it:
PUBLIC_DOWNLOAD_URL_BACKEND = 'filetransfers.backends.url.public_download_url'
```

These rely on the `file_field.url` being set (see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield)) and since your files will be on a separate server you probably need to look into [writing a custom storage backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/) for Django too. (the S3 and GAE cases assume you're using the custom Django storage backends from [here](http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/))